# Python Telethon Can't find any entity corresponding to this entity

Tags: python, api, telegram-bot, telethon

I try to access a group and want to read all massages. The problem is not the code, the problem is that I get the error: ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "Whale Alert".
But the weird thing is if I try it with other session names, sometimes it works. Does somebody know how I can get the right group 100%?
What other options do I have as input entity or session name? Maybe this could be the reason.

Here is my code:

```
with TelegramClient('Me', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    
    for message in client.iter_messages('Whale Alert'):
         #Do Sth
```

Answer (score 4):

The full error literally tells you what to study. It points to the docs:
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html#summary

This error is often encountered when trying to use an entity (user, channel, chat etc.) by only its ID. This will only work if your session has ever "seen" and thus cached the entity. That's why it's not suprising that different sessions might give you different results.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by changing the type of chat_id from str to int

Answer (score 2):

When using strings telethon checks if it's a username and if it's not it will try to get the entity from cache. in the other session, you have the name saved in your cache.

Possible solutions:

- Use the username of the chat instead of the name
- Use get_dialogs() to fill up the cache

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by printing all chats and finding the id of the chat I am interested.  After manually obtaining the id, get_entity(id) worked for me.

```
for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
  if dialog.is_channel:
      print(f'{dialog.id}:{dialog.title}')
```

Answer (score 0):

First I tried reading the documentation [here](https://arabic-telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/entities.html?highlight=entity#full-entities) if you understand the better. Instead of using the chat name only try t.me/chatname(channel link), this worked for me